# Need to fetch Annotation (Notes) for each list in dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I am trying to fetch the annotation entity (Note) associated with every list entity based on list id. I want top 1 record when sorted in descending order of created on date. For that I have  written below RESTfull call using oDATA query in button click  event of JavaScript.

```
function Button1_onclick() {
            var filterCriteria = "$select=notetext&$top=1&$orderby=createdon&$expand=List_Annotation&$filter=List_Annotation/ListId eq '" + document.getElementById("Text1").value + "'";
        SDK.JQuery.retrieveMultipleRecords(
 "Annotation",
 filterCriteria,
 function (results) {
     if (results != null) {
         alert("Success.");
     }
     else {
         alert("No notes available.");
     }
 },
 errorHandler,
 function () {
     //OnComplete handler
 }
   );
```

Comment: What is the problem you have? What error do you get?

Comment: Moved all of the code into the formatted block

Comment: @Sxntk : I did not get change to test my code yet , but is this the right way of accesing NOTE object associated with an entity ? Or is there any other SIMPLER way ?

Comment: I don't see any problems with this. Certainly, onclick event on form fields is not supported, but it work.

Comment: Should this question really still be open?  there is no known issue.  all I can see is that the op is wondering if this is the best way to do this, and the short answer is, "yes it is".